# How to use Angular Material components (specifically the slider) in an ASP.NET Core MVC and Angular project?

Tags: c#, angular, angular-material, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-components

I created a brand new ASP.NET Core MVC (Web Application - .NET Core version = 3.1) project with the Angular template:
[image: ASP.NET Core MVC Angular Project]

It comes with some basic pre-defined modules and components:
[image: Angular Demo Project]

Out of the box it works fine.
As soon as I add an import on any Angular Material module in my "app.module.ts" module, when I try to debug it locally via IIS Express, I immediately get the following error:
[image: Debugging Error]

I haven't even tried implementing the material component yet, all I did was add the import to my app.module.ts. The only other error I notice is whenever I do an `ng serve` my Console says:
[image: Angular NG Serve Console Error]
But it still starts up the Angular Server anyway.

I was following the getting started guide when I ran into this issue: https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

Here's my app.module.ts (literally no changes from what's auto-generated with the Visual Studio Angular template, other than the import statements):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';

import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
    ]),
    MatSliderModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I really want to start using Angular, but what the heck gives?

Update: Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "testangularmaterial",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run TestAngularMaterial:server:dev",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-server": "8.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.12",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "8.1.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^3.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.4.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.26",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.26",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0"
  }
}
```

Also, I noticed in this test project my Angular CLI version was 8.3.26 so I created another brand new test project (ASP.NET Core MVC) with a blank template and manually ran the ng commands to add an Angular project to it. Still running into the same exact issues as above though.

Comment: Note it doesn't make sense to VoteDown someone without an explanation why. Not sure why I was with a valid question.

Comment: Did you try npm install?

Comment: @JohnPeters Yes it didn't help, doesn't return any errors, and this is the response:

audited 1552 packages in 7.559s

36 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 279 vulnerabilities (270 low, 1 moderate, 8 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Odd because the message is saying it can't find the module, this is almost always a missing module in node_modules folder.  Are you on Angular 10?  Sometimes I delete the json.package.lock file, redo the npm install @angular/material.  Then do a "npm ci" .  This can get you out of the pacake.lock interfering which it does do.  It has a memory.

Comment: Please upload package.json

Comment: @JohnPeters So in my production application "ng --version" shows Angular 10 but interestingly my brand new test project (mentioned in my question post) is showing Angular CLI: 8.3.26 for "ng --version".

I was wondering if the Angular template from Visual Studio is out of date / whacked. So I made another test ASP.NET Core MVC project with a blank template and ran the ng commands to add a new Angular project. The CLI is now showing version 10, but I'm still running into the same issues.

Comment: @emmbee Updated my post with the package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you installed the npm dependencies in the wrong location. By default when opening the terminal in Visual Studio, it opens the terminal in the project root, but our dependencies must be installed in the ClientApp directory. Here is how to do it:

1. In VS, go to tools > Command Line > Developer command prompt.
2. Navigate to ClientApp (type `cd project-name\ClientApp`)
3. run `npm i`
4. run `ng add @angular/material`

Comment: The issue was definitely a dependency one, so your answer is close enough for me to accept. I don't believe I installed into the wrong location, but for some reason it just didn't install the Angular Material dependencies I needed until I used the --save flag. I had to do an npm i --save for both @angular/material and @angular/cdk.

Comment: That's really interesting! Maybe it wasn't even the --save flag? Did you try first following above instructions but didn't work?

Comment: I didn't get a chance to see your answer until after I fixed it. I luckily was able to stumble my way to find the --save flag and get it working eventually. But yea it was weird. The more I think about it, I'm not sure how else I could've experienced the issue I had unless I was in the wrong installation location initially, but I can't say for sure one way or the other. It's just odd that ng add and npm install both kept reporting back successes but my package.json file wasn't getting updated until my final attempt with the --save flag.